# How to unzip files in a Heroku Buildpack

Tags: heroku, buildpack, fantom

I'm writing a custom `Heroku` `buildpack` ([heroku-buildpack-fantom](https://github.com/Fantom-Factory/heroku-buildpack-fantom)) for [Fantom](http://fantom-lang.org/), and as part of the `compile` script I've downloaded a `.zip` file (from a language vendor), but how do I unzip it?

`unzip` is not a recognised command.

`gunzip` exists but [I can't use it](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/75258-using-gunzip-decompress-zip-file.html) to unzip .zip files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though (by default) Linux does not come pre-installed with `unzip`, the Heroku dyno does have a `jar` command. So the following works okay:

```
  > jar xf wotever.zip
```

Comment: If you want to specify an output directory `mkdir /tmp/target; cd /tmp/target` does the job. `jar` has an option `-C` but seems not working for extracting. As a side note, `rake` can't run `cd` you need to use `Dir.chdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run the 'file' command on it.  I got a .zip file from SourceForge that was actually bzip2 encoded and Heroku has both the bunzip2 decoder and the -j (--bzip2) option on tar to handle it.

Comment: Cheers, I had never heard of the `file` command:

[file is a standard Unix program for recognizing the type of data contained in a computer file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)